# NODEMCU 1.0 HX711 Load cell reading weird text

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, sensors, nodemcu

[image: Error reading]

Hi Guys! i have a problem with the reading with my NODEMCU where i tried this code on an arduino UNO it is working perfectly fine but until i tried to switch it to NODEMCU 1.0 which have a wifi function that i need, the reading turn out to have this type of error, i've tried looking for solution online and tried every single of them but apparently none of it help. The image is the error i have faced and the connection i have made from the nodemcu to hx711 is VCC --> Vin or 3.3v, GND --> GND, DT --> D2, SCK --> D3. 
Here's the code that i found online to use:

```
#include <HX711.h>

// Scale Settings
const int SCALE_DOUT_PIN = D2;
const int SCALE_SCK_PIN = D3;

HX711 scale(SCALE_DOUT_PIN, SCALE_SCK_PIN);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  scale.set_scale(-47740);// <- set here calibration factor!!!
  scale.tare();
}

void loop() {
  float weight = scale.get_units(1);
  Serial.println(String(weight, 3));
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Putting your whole code in comments is not helpful.  I edited your post this time, remember to select code and then ctrl+k

Comment: Sorry about that, would keep in mind about it! Appreciate your help thanks!

Comment: try D1 instead of D3. D3 is io 0, a boot configuration pin

Comment: Hi juraj! Thanks for the reply. i tried D1 and the Serial monitor now shows a reading of 0.000 all the way regardless of the weight i put on it.

Comment: Hi juraj, i have change the VCC connection from Vin to 3.3v and it work! thanks!! could you post your answer on the answer section so i could upvote? thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try D1 instead of D3. D3 is io 0, a boot configuration pin with pull-up on board.